# One Way Car Rental in Italy - Romantic idea or completely mad?

Tags: italy, car-rentals, one-way

I am flying into Italy with my husband and 2 friends to go on holiday. We are landing in the north and leaving from Brindisi airport in the south. We plan to spend a few days in/near Venice, and then want to make our way to Apulian to be there on a Saturday to meet the agent for our holiday apartment rental.

I have looked up flights and Ryanair fly out on Saturdays from Bologna to Brindisi and that could work for us, but I have this romantic notion of renting a car and driving down through Italy to Apulian.  Has anyone done a one-way rental in Italy and if so, what would you advice, or what tips would give me?

Cost wise they are not that different, a one way rental with on [Car-Booker.com](https://www.car-booker.com) is € 520.87 for 15 days, so I could also have the car when I am in Apulian. Flights are a little more expensive at first glance, but then I haven´t calcuated in fuel or Motorways on the car rental price.

Am I being a romantic, or am I mad?!!

Comment: Did you consider train for the longer distances? Italy has a good system of high speed trains for much of the country. You can still combine it with one or two shorter rentals.

Comment: Is having the road trip the whole point? A train wouldn't work in that case. It does sound like a lovely romantic drive, except I'm not sure about the two friends, but that's up to you.

Comment: The moment you ask "Is it romantic?" it is in all probability not. >_>

Comment: I find it unlikely that the cost of a one-way rental is close to the cost when the vehicle is returned to its home base. The rental companies have significant costs asscociated with returning vehicles.

Answer (score 6):

You give no dates, but if the trip is in august you're definitely mad! That month is holiday time for lots if italians and the road from N to S is heavily loaded (read as frequent traffic jams) for the major part of the month. You may avoid highways but then the trip from Venice to Apulia would be much slower because of the slower roads and also because that track is through a part of Italy that is heavily crowded during the summer season.